# How can I get Doxygen to show structs instead of classes

Tags: c, doxygen

Doxygen seems to expect C++ and lists my structs as "classes" in the HTML output.

How can I get Doxygen to process my source as C not C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C=YES
```

in your **Doxyfile**, see if that's more to liking.

Comment: That's it.. it now says "Data Structures" instead of "Classes".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `doxywizard`, you can set your in `Mode` tab.

In "`Select Programming language to Optimize the result for`"

Check "`Optimize for C or php output`"